# Confusion in selecting number of state variables

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, control-system, energy, state-space

Generally we take no. Of state variable equal to number of independent energy storing elements ,

let's take two examples -

1.a RC circuit with voltage source as an input ,so here we can take  different State variables but we need only 1minimum state variable ,so we generally take voltage across capicitor and with the help of this state variable and input we can calculate any possible system variable.

2.A partical of some  mass  and an input force ,so same as RC circuit ,it has only one energy storing element(mass) ,so it also requires only one state variable.

But in almost every books

why in case of mass elements (or mechanical systems in 2nd example) state variables are taken as position and velocity rather than only position?

isn't we unnecessary increasing one extra variable or there are some other reasons that I'm not aware?

When RC circuit and a single mass element is analogous then why 1st require only one minimum state variable while other require two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we have a mass *not connected* to a spring, we need only one state to describe the system. A mass not connected to a spring has only one energy storing element as you rightly pointed out. Mass stores kinetic energy which is a function of velocity and *not* of position. Hence, we need not consider position as a state variable.

### Example

A good example for *not* storing position as a state variable is a motor used to operate a (centrifugal) **pump**. We are *not* interested in the angular position of the motor since the rate of pumping is dependent only on the motor velocity. If you look up literature / text books where the motor state is modelled for the above purpose, only the velocity state is modelled.

> But in **almost** every books

If you have examples of books which model only one state (velocity) please edit them into to the question. It is highly likely that the example those books mention is similar to the example above.

### Reasons for adding additional states

> isn't we unnecessary increasing one extra variable or there are some other reasons that I'm not aware?

Using more state variables than the minimum number are used when (not an exhaustive list)

1. The additional state is important for the particular application
2. A sensor in the system measures that state and we want to model that sensor (e.g. a motor system where the important state is velocity, but it is not directly measured; but the position is measured using an encoder and the velocity is calculated from the position measurements)
3. The resulting system with additional states is easier to analyse. In optimal control (and optimisation) problems, additional *slack* and other (co)state variables are added to the original problem description.

Answer (score 1):

> why in case of mass elements (or mechanical systems in 2nd example) state variables are taken as position and velocity rather than only position?

I think if you read the part of the book around 'mechanical systems', you'll find that when they have two state variables, they're doing the sums for a mass-spring system. A mass and a force is fairly uninteresting, acceleration of a mass due to gravity for instance is just a quadratic in time.

With a mass and a spring, there are two energy storage elements, and it's convenient to use position for the spring potential energy and velocity for the mass kinetic energy.

Comment: Thanks for answer ! I understand your point but what about if there is no spring (as I mentioned in my question that only mass element is there ), and even if let's say there is one spring in between two masses then in books 4state variables are taken instead of 3 that what I wanted to understand

Comment: 'I read somewhere that ... ' questions don't work very well here. If there are three energy storage objects and the book says there are four, then the book is wrong, or you've misunderstood the book. Link to the publication, giving the page number, or embed a photograph of the section in your question. In the case of two masses and a spring, the conventional approach is that the three sv's are the distance between the masses giving spring energy, the differential velocity of the masses giving the centre-of-mass frame kinetic energy, and the velocity of the centre of mass.